# Why isn't the StackExchange keyboard shortcut extension in the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: feature-request, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been using the keyboard shortcut Chrome extension for ages - but each time I start using a new computer, I have to find the [blog post about it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-keyboard-shortcuts/) again to download it - then open the extensions page and drag it over, because you can't just install downloaded extensions from arbitrary sites any more.

Likewise every time the extension is updated, there's the same download/open extensions/drag rigmarole... and the extension itself needs to perform the update check, with two different versions of the extension (one auto-update-detecting, the other not).

Why isn't the extension just in the Chrome Web Store, allowing for automatic updating, automatic syncing between computers, simpler installation, and better discoverability? Is there some technical reason, or has it just not been done yet?

EDIT: As of June 12th 2014, an update to Chrome (I assume) has disabled the extension for me, and it can't be re-enabled without it being put in the Chrome Web store. See the [Chrome blog post](http://chrome.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/protecting-chrome-users-from-malicious.html) for more details. I believe that installing the Dev or Canary channel version of Chrome may fix this, but I would rather not do that on every machine I use to browse Stack Exchange. *Please* strongly consider packaging this extension up on the web store.

Comment: ... Stack Exchange's skimping on $5?

Comment: +1, I didn't know about this extension until now

Comment: I use [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) (which can sync scripts!) and (re)discover scripts over on http://stackapps.com

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that since it is not an extension but a script that is used by another extension is why it is not in the chrome web store.

If you want to use it in chrome you need to use it with the TamperMonkey extension and if you want to use it in FireFox you need the GreeseMonkey addon.

In the blog the section talking about installing it has a link that explains how to install browser scripts and what extensions you need to install them.

I would assume that if the script was ever made into an actual extension/addon for use in Chrome, FireFox or other browsers then it would show up in the official stores for the browser.

Comment: No, I just drag it into the Chrome Extensions page, where it appears *as an extension*. I don't have TamperMonkey installed at all.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected about needing tamper monkey as I didn't know it was no longer needed. And it seems like something that would be good to have updated in the blog.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's still just a userscript though, I don't know if those can be hosted in the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: The blog post doesn't say you need TamperMonkey, and neither does the page it links to. It says that's *one* way of doing it, but gives details of the other. My suggestion would eradicate most of the steps in the second way, because it would just install directly from the Chrome Web Store...

Comment: @TimStone: I certainly confess to not knowing the ins and outs of Chrome extensions etc, but it's *listed in my browser* in "Chrome Extensions". That suggests that even if a little work is required to wrap it in some appropriate metadata, it shouldn't be impossible to package it as a Chrome extension - and easily worth the effort, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry reading comprehension failure here and the post does say TamperMonkey is only one method and the other method is exactly as you described.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, [it's not a super huge deal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480985/can-a-greasemonkey-type-userscript-be-packaged-as-a-chrome-extension), it's just not something that should be necessary. I don't disagree that there are benefits, but (per the bounty message) I also have a hard time wanting to comply with this sham that Google's running to wrangle everyone into the Chrome Web Store. :/